# How to allow user to edit posts? I am using laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, eloquent, laravel-8

I am trying to allow users to edit posts, however I keep getting this error:

```
Property [caption] does not exist on this collection instance. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\myprojectname\resources\views\posts\edit-post.blade.php)
```

My edit function in Post Controller is:

```
use App\Models\Post;
     
public function edit(Post $post)
      {
    
        return view('posts.edit-post', ['post' => $post]);

      }
```

My update function in Post Controller is:

```
public function update(Post $post, Request $request)
  {

    $data = request()->validate([
      'caption' => 'nullable',
      'url' => 'nullable',
      'image' => 'nullable',
    ]);

    $updateData = [
     'caption' => $data['caption'],
     'url' => $data['url'],
   ];

   if (request('image')) {
     $imagePath = request('image')->store('uploads', 'public');
     $updateData['image'] = $imagePath;
   }

   auth()->user()->posts()->id()->update($updateData);

   return redirect('/users/' . auth()->user()->id);

  }
```

My edit-post.blade.php file code is:

```
@section('content')
<body class="create_body">
  <div class="create_container_div">

    <form action="{{('/users/' . auth()->user()->id)}}" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
      @csrf
      @method('PATCH')

      <div class="form-group">
          <label for="caption" class="create_caption_label">Post Caption</label>

          <div class="create_caption_div">
              <input id="caption"
              type="text"
              class="form-control @error('caption') is-invalid @enderror"
              name="caption"
              value="{{ old('caption') ?? auth()->user()->posts->caption }}"
              autocomplete="caption" autofocus>

              @error('caption')
              <div class="invalid-feedback-div">
                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                </span>
              </div>
              @enderror
          </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
          <label for="url" class="edit_title_label">URL</label>

          <div class="edit_url_div">
              <input id="url"
              type="text"
              class="form-control @error('url') is-invalid @enderror"
              name="url"
              value="{{ old('url') ?? auth()->user()->posts->url }}"
              autocomplete="url" autofocus>

              @error('url')
              <div class="invalid-feedback-div">
                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                </span>
              </div>
              @enderror
          </div>
      </div>

      <div class="create_post_image_div">
        <label for="image" class="create_image_label">Post Image</label>
        <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="image" name="image">

        @error('image')
        <div class="invalid-feedback-div">
          <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
        </div>
        @enderror

        <div class="create_post_btn_div">
          <button class="create_post_btn">Save Changes</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </form>

  </div>
</body>
@endsection
```

My create_posts_table migration file is:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreatePostsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->string('caption');
            $table->string('url');
            $table->string('image');
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->index('user_id');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('posts');
    }
}
```

And my Post.php model file is:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $guarded = [];

    public function user()
    {
      return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

}
```

Finally my routes in web.php are:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\PostsController;

Route::get('/posts/{post}/edit', [PostsController::class, 'edit']);

Route::patch('/posts/{post}', [PostsController::class, 'update'])->name('posts.update');
```

How can I resolve this issue, and furthermore, how do I allow users to edit posts?

Comment: `Post::where('id')->first();` ... `where('id')` what? Missing a parameter. And, you already get `$post` via the method parameter

Comment: `use App\Http\Controllers\PostsController` is missing a `;`, should throw an error

Comment: " use App\Http\Controllers\PostsController is missing a ; " Sorry, I copy and pasted that wrong by leaving out ' ; ' when really I already had it properly typed in file.

Comment: " Post::where('id')->first(); ... where('id') what? Missing a parameter. And, you already get $post via the method parameter " .  I figured as much, though I was trying a suggestion that the error was coming up because I had to loop through an array of posts to get the id of the one to be edited. Hence the error that Property [caption] does not exist on this collection instance. Now I'm not sure what to try...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is not correct, i don't know if you are coming from some other language, this makes no sense at all for me.

```
auth()->user()->posts()->id()->update($updateData);
```

You have the `Post` already in the context you are, due to it being Model bound in your controller method `public function update(Post $post, Request $request)`, you can use that to just update it. `fill()` applies you `$updateData` to the model and `save()` writes it to the database.

```
$post->fill($updateData);
$post->save();
```

As the comments stated, the edit function is missing an id, again you have already bound your model to the method, then just use it.

```
public function edit(Post $post)
{
    return view('posts.edit-post', ['post' => $post]);
}
```

Comment: This was my previous code, but the same error came up.

Comment: " Post::where('id')->first(); ... where('id') what? Missing a parameter. And, you already get $post via the method parameter " . I figured as much, though I was trying a suggestion that the error was coming up because I had to loop through an array of posts to get the id of the one to be edited. Hence the error that Property [caption] does not exist on this collection instance. Now I'm not sure what to try...

Comment: "This line is not correct, i don't know if you are coming from some other language, this makes no sense at all for me: auth()->user()->posts()->id()->update($updateData); " This line worked in a similar use case, where it helped to allow for a user to edit profile details without have to resubmit the same profile image again in the form. I wanted to use the same logic for posts, except I thought I might have to specify getting the post id to resolve error. Hence, i included the id() in that line of code.

Comment: In both cases you have the Post from the model binding so just use $post instead of fetching it or using relationship to getting it?

Comment: Okay, I did. It's working. However I now have an issue that whenever I edit and save changes to one post all other posts take on those same changes. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66619814/why-is-it-that-when-i-edit-and-save-changes-to-one-post-all-the-other-posts-tak

Comment: As stated in my answer dont do that relationship update you are doing, just update the $post same as the guy in the new question said. If this helped you fix the problem, please accept is as the answer :)

Comment: It did work. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: then please accept the answer so people coming later for this post can see it solved the problem.

Comment: Sorry, didn't know exactly what you meant by accept the answer. I'm brand new to stack overflow. I just hit the check mark. Thanks again