# Why is it that when I edit and save changes to one post, all the other posts take on those same changes? How can I fix? I am using laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, foreach, laravel-8

Whenever I try to save changes to only one post, the outcome is that all other posts I have take on those same changes.

My routes in web.php are:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\PostsController;

Route::get('/posts/{post}/edit', [PostsController::class, 'edit']);

Route::patch('/posts/{post}', [PostsController::class, 'update'])->name('posts.update');
```

My edit function in Posts Controller is:

```
public function edit(Post $post)
  {
    return view('posts.edit-post', ['post' => $post]);
  }
```

My update function in Posts Controller is:

```
public function update(Post $post, Request $request)
  {
    $data = request()->validate([
      'caption' => 'required',
      'url' => 'required',
      'image' => ['required', 'image'],
    ]);

    $imagePath = request('image')->store('uploads', 'public');

    auth()->user()->posts()->update([
      'caption' => $data['caption'],
      'url' => $data['url'],
      'image' => $imagePath,
    ]);

    return redirect('/users/' . auth()->user()->id);

  }
```

My form in edit-post.blade.php file is:

```
<form action="{{('/posts/' . $post->id)}}" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
      @csrf
      @method('PATCH')

      <div class="form-group">
          <label for="caption" class="create_caption_label">Post Caption</label>

          <div class="create_caption_div">
              <input id="caption"
              type="text"
              class="form-control @error('caption') is-invalid @enderror"
              name="caption"
              value="{{ old('caption') ?? $post->caption }}"
              autocomplete="caption" autofocus>

              @error('caption')
              <div class="invalid-feedback-div">
                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                </span>
              </div>
              @enderror
          </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
          <label for="url" class="edit_title_label">URL</label>

          <div class="edit_url_div">
              <input id="url"
              type="text"
              class="form-control @error('url') is-invalid @enderror"
              name="url"
              value="{{ old('url') ?? $post->url }}"
              autocomplete="url" autofocus>

              @error('url')
              <div class="invalid-feedback-div">
                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                </span>
              </div>
              @enderror
          </div>
      </div>

      <div class="create_post_image_div">
        <label for="image" class="create_image_label">Post Image</label>
        <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="image" name="image">

        @error('image')
        <div class="invalid-feedback-div">
          <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
        </div>
        @enderror

        <div class="create_post_btn_div">
          <button class="create_post_btn">Save Changes</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </form>
```

And finally, here is the profile.blade.php file, where I would like to output the posts' data to:

```
@foreach( $user->posts as $post )
              <div class="carousel_posts_container">

                <div class="post_date_and_edit_div">
             
                  <div class="post_edit_div">
                    <form action="/posts/{{$post->id}}/edit">
                      <input class="post_edit_btn" type="submit" value="• • •">
                    </form>
                  </div>
                </div>
             
                <div class="carousel_post_img_div">
                  <img src="/storage/{{ $post->image }}" class="carousel_img_placeholder">
                </div>                  

                <div class="carousel_caption_container">

                  <div class="carousel_caption_div">
                    <p class="carousel_caption_username">{{$user->username}} - {{$post->caption}}</p>
                  </div>

                </div>

              </div>
 @endforeach
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your controller replace this:

```
auth()->user()->posts()->update([
  'caption' => $data['caption'],
  'url' => $data['url'],
  'image' => $imagePath,
]);
```

with this:

```
$post->update([
  'caption' => $data['caption'],
  'url' => $data['url'],
  'image' => $imagePath,
]);
```

There you've just updated all the related posts of authenticated user. For the specific post you need to update that specific instance only.
If your current code is working well, then I believe that should be work after that small change as well.